# Spacy Sentence Boundary Detection Exclusion

Tags: python, spacy

I'm working with a corpus of annotated docx documents. The annotations are made using comments. I extracted the text and comments from the documents and created some placeholders in the raw text which shows where the annotation starts and where it ends. An example would be:

```
Lorem ipsum <|n|> dolor sit amet, consectetur <||n||> adipiscing elit.
```

where `n` is the id of annotation. later on I would segment the document into sentences and use regex to find which annotation belongs to which sentence.

Now, I'm using python-spacy as follows:

```
...
doc = self.nlp(unicode(self.raw_text))
for sentence in doc.sents:
   #extract annotations and save the sentence
```

However the sentence boundary detection on spacy in some cases segments the text from where the annotation begins so I wind up having lots of sentences which are incomplete or simply contain an '<' charterer. My question is, is there someway that I could make the spacy ignore the annotation tokens?